# Como resolver erros destes Codigo?

Tags: c#

Estou a desenvolver um sistema de venda, usando visual Studio 2013 e o SQL 2008, por alguns inconvenientes passei a usar o Visual Studio 2012, acontece que estou a ter um erro. O código esta certo mas ao executar este apresenta erro, em quanto usava o Visual Studio 2013 executava normalmente.

```
 private void dgv_Artigo_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            this.txt_ID.Text = dgv_Artigo[0, dgv_Artigo.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString();
            this.txt_CodBarra.Text = dgv_Artigo[1, dgv_Artigo.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString();
            this.txt_Artigo.Text = dgv_Artigo[2, dgv_Artigo.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString();
            this.cb_Categoria.Text = dgv_Artigo[5, dgv_Artigo.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString();
            this.cb_TipoArtigo.Text = dgv_Artigo[6, dgv_Artigo.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString();

            SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection(CN);
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM view_artigo where id_artigo = '" + dgv_Artigo.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString() + "'", conexao);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adp.Fill(dt);
            byte[] imagembinaria = (byte[])dt.Rows[0][0];
            Bitmap ima;
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imagembinaria))
            {
                ima = new Bitmap(ms);
            }
            pt_imagem.Image = ima;

            tabControl1.SelectTab(tabPage1);
        }
```

Comment: Você poderia informar qual erro está ocorrendo?

Comment: O indice esta fora do intervalo. Tem de ser não negativo e inferior ao tamanho da colecção.

Comment: Em que linha ocorre? Se tem erro o código certamente não está certo. O fato de funcionar em alguma situação só significa que o erro não acontece em todas situações. Quando funciona é coincidência. De onde vem `dgv_Artigo.CurrentRow.Index`? aparentemente o que tem nele está errado. Tem certeza que o *array* tem pelo menos 7 elementos na primeira dimensão? Esse `using` pode estar errado, está descartando o objeto e depois usando algo que foi descartado, não faz sentido, a não ser que o `Bitmap` faça uma cópia do objeto, não tenho certeza se faz.

Answer (score 1):

A versão mínima da Framework suportada pelo visual Studio 2012 é a 4.5 pode ser que seu projeto esteja usando a 4.5.1 ou superior

Comment: Gratos, pela resposta, agora sim intendi o porque que no outro meu pc que tem o Visual Studio 2013 estava a executar normalmente e neste pc que estou a usar atualmente esta a dar erro.

Comment: Amigo, marque as respostas que lhe ajudaram por favor